# Can't display MongoLab data on deployed Heroku website

Tags: mongodb, express, heroku, handlebars.js, mlab

I recently deployed my genetic data application (using the 23andMe API) to Heroku and integrated Universal SSL using Cloudflare. My data is stored in a free Sandbox plan using the MLab addon on Heroku. The 23andMe data is stored in MLab. As soon as I added my website to Cloudflare, the data would rarely display on the page. 99% of the time the MLab data doesn't display, but on 1% of the time it does.

```
router.get('/tools/my-genetics', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  var data = {};
  if(req.user) {

   SNPs.find({user_id: req.user._id}).then(function(result) {
    data.genes = result;


   })

   res.render('tools/gene_data', {
    data: data,
    user: req.user,
    layout: 'dash'
   });
  }
});
```

I don't know why it worked in my local environment and when using the domain name provided by Heroku, but stopped working as soon as I configured Universal SSL and added a custom domain name to Heroku. I am using Handlebars.js to bind the data to my `.handlebars` file. Can anyone tell me why I can't grab data from MLAB and display it in my handlebars file when Cloudflare is configured?

Could it be Cloudflare's Firewall Access rules?

My view looks like this:

```
   {{#each}}
    <ul class="list-group">
     <li class="list-group-item lead">1. For {{diseases.0.snp}}, your Genotype is {{genotypes.rs28936694}}. This snp is {{diseases.0.risk}} {{diseases.0.descr}} This snp is located on {{diseases.0.location}}.
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item lead">2. For {{diseases.1.snp}}, your Genotype is {{genotypes.rs3825942}}. {{diseases.1.risk}} {{diseases.1.descr}} This snp is located on {{diseases.1.location}}.
     </li> 
     <li class="list-group-item lead">3. For {{diseases.8.snp}}, your Genotype is {{genotypes.rs1048661}}. {{diseases.8.risk}} {{diseases.8.descr}} This snp is located on {{diseases.8.location}}.
     </li>
    </ul>
   {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with my database query. I added an `if/else` statement and it worked.

```
router.get('/tools/my-genetics', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  var data = {};

  SNPs.find({user_id: req.user._id}).exec(function(err, result) {
    data.genes = result;


    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }else {
      console.log('===result inside here===: ' + result);

      res.render('tools/gene_data', {
        data: data,
        user: req.user,
        layout: 'dash'
      });      
    }
  });
});
```